# E:M Error on a NodeMCU lua code

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

i'm here to ask you some help about an error that happen during the execution of my code. I' m coding on a Adafruit Feather HUZZAH ESP8266 board with the latest NodeMCU master firmware using Lua. I want to read values from a .bin file in an SD card and show it on the Monitor near its decimal address position, the rest of the project it s to write it on a ROM with SPI but before  i have to resolve this, so there is some commented code that is unnecessary.

This is the code :

```
    function WriteAByte()
    spi.setup(1, spi.MASTER, spi.CPOL_LOW, spi.CPHA_LOW, 8, 8)
    vol = file.mount("/SD0", 2)
    file.open("/SD0/bios.bin","r")
    file.seek("set", seek)
    bytes = file.read(1)
    print(seek.." "..bytes)
    seek = file.seek("cur")
    file.close()
    if(bytes == nil)then
      mytimer:stop()
      print("FINISHED TO WRITE")
    else 
        -- set SPI BIOS
        --spi.setup(1, spi.MASTER, spi.CPOL_LOW, spi.CPHA_LOW, 8, 8)
        --spi.set_mosi(1,0,8,bytes)
        --spi.transaction(1, 8,0x03, 24, index, 8, 0, 0)
        --index = index + 0x000001
    end
end

mytimer = tmr.create()

index = 0x000000
seek = 0
bytes = 0



mytimer:register(100, tmr.ALARM_AUTO,WriteAByte)
mytimer:start()
```

The code works but after 64 bytes (always 64) the program stop to work and tell me

```
        0 �
1 �
2 �
3 �
4 �
5 �
6 �
7 �
8 �
9 �
10 �
11 �
12 �
13 �
14 �
15 �
16 Z
17 �
18 �
19 
20 
21 
22 
23 
24 
25 
26 
27 
28  
29 
30 !
31 
32 �
33 �
34 �
35 �
36 �
37 �
38 �
39 �
40 �
41 �
42 �
43 �
44 �
45 �
46 �
47 �
48 D
49 
50 �
51 d
52 
53 
54 
55 
56 
57 
58 
59 
60 �
61 �
62 �
63 �
64 
E:M 568
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (application.lua:5: open a file first)

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x40100000, len 26996, room 16 
tail 4
chksum 0x80
load 0x3ffe8000, len 2380, room 4 
tail 8
chksum 0xf5
load 0x3ffe894c, len 136, room 0 
tail 8
chksum 0xd7
csum 0xd7
```

I thinked about a Serial Monitor Buff Saturation so i tried it without the printing of the seek and bytes but it went in the same error. After i thinked about a problem on the 65 bytes so i set seek to an higher value than 65 but it read only 64 bytes of the rest and after it goes in error with the same code. So i think it is something like a memory saturation error but calling the garbage collecting function to see free memory  tell always the same value of free memory in every cycle and if i garbage collect every cycle the error doen t disappear.
I read something about a heap memory saturation so i tried to call the function in a separate file with dofile every cycle and keep some variables of the function local but this didn t helped. How can i fix this problem ?
I can t upload the binary but it is 64 MB and i read 1 Bytes for cycle and i dont think the problem is the file.

UPDATE

this are the new code files:

init.lua

```
dofile("afterInit.lua")
```

afterInit.lua

```
function f()
    print("Heap all'avvio del timer : "..node.heap()) 
    if(semaphore3 == 0)then
        mytimer2:start()
    end
end

function ff()
    print("Heap all'avvio del timer2 : "..node.heap())
    semaphore3 = 1
    print("Heap dopo assegnazione semaphore3 in timer2 : "..node.heap())
    dofile("application.lua")
end

semaphore1 = 0
semaphore2 = 0
semaphore3 = 0

index = 0x000000
seek = 0
bytes = 0

mytimer = tmr.create()
mytimer2 = tmr.create()
mytimer:register(100, tmr.ALARM_AUTO,f)
mytimer2:register(1, tmr.ALARM_SEMI,ff)
mytimer:start()
```

application.lua

```
print("Heap all'avvio di application.lua : "..node.heap())
if(semaphore1 == 0)then
    print("Heap all'avvio 1 di a.lua : "..node.heap())
    semaphore1 = 1
    dofile("a.lua")
end
if(semaphore1 == 0)then
    print("Heap alla chiusura 1 di a.lua : "..node.heap())

    collectgarbage ()
    tmr.delay(50)
    print("Heap dopo garbace collector : "..node.heap())
    print((seek-1).." "..bytes)
    print("Heap dopo controllo semaphore1 in application : "..node.heap())
    if(semaphore2 == 0)then
        print("Heap all'avvio 1 di b.lua : "..node.heap())
        semaphore2 = 1
        dofile("b.lua")
    end
    if(semaphore2 == 0)then
        print("Heap alla chiusura 1 di b.lua : "..node.heap())
        print("Heap alla chiusura di application.lua : "..node.heap())
        semaphore3 = 0
    else
        print("Heap al riavvio di application: "..node.heap())
        dofile("application.lua")
    end
else
    print("Heap al riavvio di application: "..node.heap())
    dofile("application.lua")
end
```

a.lua

```
print("A a.lua : "..node.heap())
spi.setup(1, spi.MASTER, spi.CPOL_LOW, spi.CPHA_LOW, 8, 8)
print("B a.lua : "..node.heap())
local vol = file.mount("/SD0", 2)
print("C a.lua : "..node.heap())
local bios = file.open("/SD0/bios.bin","r")
print("D a.lua : "..node.heap())
print(bios)
print("E a.lua : "..node.heap())
print(seek)
print("F a.lua : "..node.heap())
bios:seek("set", seek)
print("G a.lua : "..node.heap())
bytes = bios.read(1)
print("H a.lua : "..node.heap())
seek = bios:seek("cur")
print("I a.lua : "..node.heap())
bios:close()
print("J a.lua : "..node.heap())
semaphore1 = 0
print("K a.lua : "..node.heap())
print("Heap alla chiusura 2 di a.lua : "..node.heap())
```

b.lua

```
print("Heap all'avvio 2 di b.lua : "..node.heap())
--if(bytes == nil)then
if(seek > 8)then
    mytimer:stop()
    print("FINISHED TO WRITE")
else 
    -- set SPI BIOS
    --spi.setup(1, spi.MASTER, spi.CPOL_LOW, spi.CPHA_LOW, 8, 8)
    --spi.set_mosi(1,0,8,bytes)
    --spi.transaction(1, 8,0x03, 24, index, 8, 0, 0)
    --index = index + 0x000001
end
semaphore2 = 0
print("Heap alla chiusura 2 di b.lua : "..node.heap())
```

And that are the Output Lines:

```
add if1
dhcp server start:(ip:192.168.4.1,mask:255.255.255.0,gw:192.168.4.1)
bcn 100

_flash_used_end:402bb570
fs.start:c0000,max:33b000
_flash_used_end:402bb570
fs.start:c0000,max:33a000
_flash_used_end:402bb570
fs.start:d0000,max:32b000
_flash_used_end:402bb570
fs.start:d0000,max:32a000
mount res: 0, 0
Task task_lua started.
nul mode, fpm auto sleep set:enalbe

NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
    branch: master
    commit: 67027c0d05f7e8d1b97104e05a3715f6ebc8d07f
    SSL: true
    modules: adc,crypto,encoder,file,gpio,http,i2c,mdns,net,node,pwm,rtcfifo,rtcmem,rtctime,sjson,spi,tmr,uart,websocket,wifi,wifi_monitor,wps,tls
 build created on 2018-05-13 04:40
 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 2.2.1(cfd48f3)
> Heap size::38928.
Heap all'avvio del timer : 38928
Heap all'avvio del timer2 : 40216
Heap dopo assegnazione semaphore3 in timer2 : 40216
Heap all'avvio di application.lua : 37224
Heap all'avvio 1 di a.lua : 38248
A a.lua : 33744
B a.lua : 35904
Function platform_gpio_mode() is called. pin_mux:1610614844, func:0
C a.lua : 35288
D a.lua : 34712
userdata: 0x3fff21b8
E a.lua : 34560
0
F a.lua : 34680
G a.lua : 34640
H a.lua : 34680
I a.lua : 34608
J a.lua : 35176
K a.lua : 35168
Heap alla chiusura 2 di a.lua : 35176
Heap alla chiusura 1 di a.lua : 35144
Heap dopo garbace collector : 37704
0 �
Heap dopo controllo semaphore1 in application : 37616
Heap all'avvio 1 di b.lua : 37568
Heap all'avvio 2 di b.lua : 36368
Heap alla chiusura 2 di b.lua : 36864
Heap alla chiusura 1 di b.lua : 36864
Heap alla chiusura di application.lua : 37584
Heap all'avvio del timer : 37576
Heap all'avvio del timer2 : 39552
Heap dopo assegnazione semaphore3 in timer2 : 39552
Heap all'avvio di application.lua : 36544
Heap all'avvio 1 di a.lua : 37584
A a.lua : 33088
B a.lua : 35248
Function platform_gpio_mode() is called. pin_mux:1610614844, func:0
C a.lua : 34624
D a.lua : 34048
userdata: 0x3fff2598
E a.lua : 33896
1
F a.lua : 34016
G a.lua : 33976
H a.lua : 33976
I a.lua : 33976
J a.lua : 34544
K a.lua : 34544
Heap alla chiusura 2 di a.lua : 34544
Heap alla chiusura 1 di a.lua : 34512
Heap dopo garbace collector : 37064
1 �
Heap dopo controllo semaphore1 in application : 37000
Heap all'avvio 1 di b.lua : 36952
Heap all'avvio 2 di b.lua : 35760
Heap alla chiusura 2 di b.lua : 36256
Heap alla chiusura 1 di b.lua : 36256
Heap alla chiusura di application.lua : 36960
Heap all'avvio del timer : 36960
Heap all'avvio del timer2 : 38928
Heap dopo assegnazione semaphore3 in timer2 : 38928
Heap all'avvio di application.lua : 35896
Heap all'avvio 1 di a.lua : 36936
A a.lua : 32432
B a.lua : 34616
Function platform_gpio_mode() is called. pin_mux:1610614844, func:0
C a.lua : 33992
D a.lua : 33408
userdata: 0x3fff23e8
E a.lua : 33240
2
F a.lua : 33376
G a.lua : 33328
H a.lua : 33336
I a.lua : 33328
J a.lua : 33904
K a.lua : 33896
Heap alla chiusura 2 di a.lua : 33904
Heap alla chiusura 1 di a.lua : 33872
Heap dopo garbace collector : 36416
2 �
Heap dopo controllo semaphore1 in application : 36336
Heap all'avvio 1 di b.lua : 36296
Heap all'avvio 2 di b.lua : 35080
Heap alla chiusura 2 di b.lua : 35576
Heap alla chiusura 1 di b.lua : 35576
Heap alla chiusura di application.lua : 36304
Heap all'avvio del timer : 36304
Heap all'avvio del timer2 : 38304
Heap dopo assegnazione semaphore3 in timer2 : 38304
Heap all'avvio di application.lua : 35296
Heap all'avvio 1 di a.lua : 36328
A a.lua : 31832
B a.lua : 34000
Function platform_gpio_mode() is called. pin_mux:1610614844, func:0
C a.lua : 33376
D a.lua : 32800
userdata: 0x3fff2608
E a.lua : 32640
3
F a.lua : 32768
G a.lua : 32720
H a.lua : 32720
I a.lua : 32728
J a.lua : 33288
K a.lua : 33296
Heap alla chiusura 2 di a.lua : 33288
Heap alla chiusura 1 di a.lua : 33264
Heap dopo garbace collector : 35808
3 �
Heap dopo controllo semaphore1 in application : 35736
Heap all'avvio 1 di b.lua : 35696
Heap all'avvio 2 di b.lua : 34472
Heap alla chiusura 2 di b.lua : 34968
Heap alla chiusura 1 di b.lua : 34968
Heap alla chiusura di application.lua : 35704
Heap all'avvio del timer : 35704
Heap all'avvio del timer2 : 37680
Heap dopo assegnazione semaphore3 in timer2 : 37680
Heap all'avvio di application.lua : 34696
Heap all'avvio 1 di a.lua : 35736
A a.lua : 31232
B a.lua : 33392
Function platform_gpio_mode() is called. pin_mux:1610614844, func:0
C a.lua : 32768
D a.lua : 32192
userdata: 0x3fff2128
E a.lua : 32040
4
F a.lua : 32160
G a.lua : 32120
H a.lua : 32120
I a.lua : 32112
J a.lua : 32688
K a.lua : 32680
Heap alla chiusura 2 di a.lua : 32688
Heap alla chiusura 1 di a.lua : 32664
Heap dopo garbace collector : 35216
4 �
Heap dopo controllo semaphore1 in application : 35144
Heap all'avvio 1 di b.lua : 35096
Heap all'avvio 2 di b.lua : 33896
Heap alla chiusura 2 di b.lua : 34392
Heap alla chiusura 1 di b.lua : 34392
Heap alla chiusura di application.lua : 35112
Heap all'avvio del timer : 35104
Heap all'avvio del timer2 : 37056
Heap dopo assegnazione semaphore3 in timer2 : 37056
Heap all'avvio di application.lua : 34088
Heap all'avvio 1 di a.lua : 35112
A a.lua : 30640
B a.lua : 32800
Function platform_gpio_mode() is called. pin_mux:1610614844, func:0
C a.lua : 32176
D a.lua : 31600
userdata: 0x3fff2148
E a.lua : 31448
5
F a.lua : 31568
G a.lua : 31528
H a.lua : 31528
I a.lua : 31528
J a.lua : 32096
K a.lua : 32096
Heap alla chiusura 2 di a.lua : 32096
Heap alla chiusura 1 di a.lua : 32072
Heap dopo garbace collector : 34592
5 �
Heap dopo controllo semaphore1 in application : 34528
Heap all'avvio 1 di b.lua : 34480
Heap all'avvio 2 di b.lua : 33288
Heap alla chiusura 2 di b.lua : 33784
Heap alla chiusura 1 di b.lua : 33784
Heap alla chiusura di application.lua : 34488
Heap all'avvio del timer : 34488
Heap all'avvio del timer2 : 36432
Heap dopo assegnazione semaphore3 in timer2 : 36432
Heap all'avvio di application.lua : 33456
Heap all'avvio 1 di a.lua : 34488
A a.lua : 29984
B a.lua : 32144
Function platform_gpio_mode() is called. pin_mux:1610614844, func:0
C a.lua : 31520
D a.lua : 30944
userdata: 0x3fff2128
E a.lua : 30792
6
F a.lua : 30912
G a.lua : 30872
H a.lua : 30872
I a.lua : 30864
J a.lua : 31440
K a.lua : 31432
Heap alla chiusura 2 di a.lua : 31440
Heap alla chiusura 1 di a.lua : 31416
Heap dopo garbace collector : 33968
6 �
Heap dopo controllo semaphore1 in application : 33896
Heap all'avvio 1 di b.lua : 33856
Heap all'avvio 2 di b.lua : 32648
Heap alla chiusura 2 di b.lua : 33136
Heap alla chiusura 1 di b.lua : 33136
Heap alla chiusura di application.lua : 33856
Heap all'avvio del timer : 33856
Heap all'avvio del timer2 : 35808
Heap dopo assegnazione semaphore3 in timer2 : 35808
Heap all'avvio di application.lua : 32816
Heap all'avvio 1 di a.lua : 33840
A a.lua : 29336
B a.lua : 31496
Function platform_gpio_mode() is called. pin_mux:1610614844, func:0
C a.lua : 30872
D a.lua : 30296
userdata: 0x3fff2198
E a.lua : 30144
7
F a.lua : 30264
G a.lua : 30224
H a.lua : 30224
I a.lua : 30216
J a.lua : 30792
K a.lua : 30784
Heap alla chiusura 2 di a.lua : 30792
Heap alla chiusura 1 di a.lua : 30768
Heap dopo garbace collector : 33328
7 �
Heap dopo controllo semaphore1 in application : 33256
Heap all'avvio 1 di b.lua : 33208
Heap all'avvio 2 di b.lua : 32008
Heap alla chiusura 2 di b.lua : 32496
Heap alla chiusura 1 di b.lua : 32496
Heap alla chiusura di application.lua : 33208
Heap all'avvio del timer : 33208
Heap all'avvio del timer2 : 35184
Heap dopo assegnazione semaphore3 in timer2 : 35184
Heap all'avvio di application.lua : 32224
Heap all'avvio 1 di a.lua : 33240
A a.lua : 28704
B a.lua : 30864
Function platform_gpio_mode() is called. pin_mux:1610614844, func:0
C a.lua : 30240
D a.lua : 29664
userdata: 0x3fff2198
E a.lua : 29512
8
F a.lua : 29632
G a.lua : 29592
H a.lua : 29592
I a.lua : 29592
J a.lua : 30160
K a.lua : 30160
Heap alla chiusura 2 di a.lua : 30160
Heap alla chiusura 1 di a.lua : 30136
Heap dopo garbace collector : 32728
8 �
Heap dopo controllo semaphore1 in application : 32648
Heap all'avvio 1 di b.lua : 32600
Heap all'avvio 2 di b.lua : 31416
FINISHED TO WRITE
Heap alla chiusura 2 di b.lua : 31976
Heap alla chiusura 1 di b.lua : 31896
Heap alla chiusura di application.lua : 32616
```

I think the problems are is the allocation of vol and bios but i tried garbagecollecting, putting them nil and garbagecollecting, putting them local,
putting them local and garbagecollecting. Lua VM doesn t free their space that takes circa 600 in the heap every cicle between B and C and C and D printing, please i need help on this

Comment: Can you trim your sample code even further (to circle in on the problematic lines) and maybe enable debug output when you build the firmware?

Comment: updated, please help me i need this to work

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the problem. It s because usedata structure like vol and bios are made by c function calls. They can be collected by the garbage collector if there is no pointer to them but only if you use a method implemented by them to free their internal references to their private data allocated by their library in their creator function. So bios:close() is let bios to be relased, but vol, that hasn t no more a vol:umount() function implemented cant be released. So every cycle it allocate a new vol without disallocate the previous one